# DynamicDataDisplay chart horizontal string axis

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I need to draw some charts using DynamicDataDisplay3. Everything works fine, except I can't find a way to change X axis to strings instead of dates or integers. This is how I tried to do it but I get only 1 value on X axis:

```
int i = 0;
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        i++;
                        Analyze build = new Analyze();
                        build.id = i;
                        build.build = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
                        builds.Add(build);
                        n1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]));
                    }
                }

                var datesDataSource = new EnumerableDataSource<Analyze>(builds);
                datesDataSource.SetXMapping(x => x.id);
                var numberOpenDataSource = new EnumerableDataSource<int>(n1);
                numberOpenDataSource.SetYMapping(y => y);

                CompositeDataSource compositeDataSource1 = new CompositeDataSource(datesDataSource, numberOpenDataSource);
                chBuild.AddLineGraph(compositeDataSource1, new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 2), new CirclePointMarker { Size = 6, Fill = Brushes.Blue }, new PenDescription(Convert.ToString(cmbBuildVertical.SelectedItem)));
                chBuild.Viewport.FitToView();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made my own LabelProvider to handle something similar to this. I wanted to override my DateTime labels into integers, to represent something different. In your case you could use something like this :

```
public class StringLabelProvider : NumericLabelProviderBase {

    private List<String> m_Labels;
    public List<String> Labels {
        get { return m_Labels; }
        set { m_Labels = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ToStringLabelProvider"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public StringLabelProvider(List<String> labels) {                                                
        Labels = labels;                                    
    }

    public override UIElement[] CreateLabels(ITicksInfo<double> ticksInfo) {            

        var ticks = ticksInfo.Ticks;
        Init(ticks);            

        UIElement[] res = new UIElement[ticks.Length];
        LabelTickInfo<double> tickInfo = new LabelTickInfo<double> { Info = ticksInfo.Info };
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++) {
            tickInfo.Tick = ticks[i];
            tickInfo.Index = i;
            string labelText = "";

            labelText = Labels[Convert.ToInt32(tickInfo.Tick)];

            TextBlock label = (TextBlock)GetResourceFromPool();
            if (label == null) {
                label = new TextBlock();
            }

            label.Text = labelText;

            res[i] = label;

            ApplyCustomView(tickInfo, label);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

You can construct your list of ticks, and send it to the LabelProvider you create. Like this :

```
StringLabelProvider labelProvider = new StringLabelProvider(yourLabelList);
yourAxis.LabelProvider = labelProvider;
```